# Tracking a robot in circular motion using Kalman Filter

Tags: python, kalman-filter

**What I'm trying to do:**

- Localize the robot moving in a circular motion using Kalman Filter or Extended Kalman Filter
- Using trigonometry and linear algebra, I am able to predict a "circular motion," but I wanted to find out if I can use the Kalman Filter to localize the robot *(without assuming it's in the circular motion)*
- The robot senses its coordinate (x, y).

**What I'm having a trouble with:**

- The state vectors from Kalman Filter converges to the center of the circle
- The Kalman Filter fails to find the true positions
- Screenshot: [Robot vs Kalman Filter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ejtSr.png)

**My code Implementation**

- [Gist Link](https://gist.github.com/kkweon/89fcf07705a3e4f68179362912e164e4)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think there are two issues here. One is that you are missing the process covariance matrix Q. If your state transition model is not perfect this will give the algorithm a hint of how uncertain the prediction is. A large Q will make the algorithm rely more on the measurements. 
Try initialising

```
self.q = 0.001*self.f.dot(self.f.transpose())
```

and later in the predict function

```
self.p = self.f.dot(self.p).dot(self.f.transpose()) + self.q
```

The other issue is that you are measuring a circular (polar) movement in an cartesian plane. The rotation gives an acceleration in X and Y and it is missing in the F matrix. I would update the F matrix to include the complete physical model including acceleration. The time step (dT) is also missing and could be added as an argument.

```
class KalmanFilter(Filter):
    def __init__(self, sigma, dT):
    ...
    self.f = np.array([[1, 0, dT, 0, dT*dT/2,   0],
                       [0, 1, 0, dT,   0, dT*dT/2],
                       [0, 0, 1, 0,   dT,   0],
                       [0, 0, 0, 1,   0,   dT],
                       [0, 0, 0, 0,   1,   0],
                       [0, 0, 0, 0,   0,   1]])
```

and finally in your main function

```
KF = KalmanFilter(sigma=1,dT=0.1)
```

I also increased sigma to 1 to get a smoother prediction and decreased the P initialisation to 1 from 999 to visualize the initial overshoot.

Here is the result:
[image]

Comment: Thank you. I didn't think Q was important because I thought it's a small "noise" matrix. I was so wrong. Thanks again. I can sleep in peace now.